# Не нравится напичканность студии

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sdk, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Весьма странный вопрос. Я раньше писал приложения в AIDE. Вот как там все было

- Классы, интерфейсы, синтаксис и т.д - синий
- Названия методов, переменных и т.д - белый
- Цифры, кавычки и текст в кавычках - розовый

Все пишешь сам, код на весь экран и навигация по файлам. Больше ничего.

Перешёл на студию. Много всяких значков, код выделен ужасно. Писать невозможно. Вечно предлагает все исправить, мешает по полной. Не нравится. Хочу полностью избавить студию от излишней самостоятельности и активности. Как это можно настроить?

Comment: можно полностью отказаться от студи. используйте любой редактор для кода и собирайте проект в командной строке.

Comment: Это можно сделать даже не открывая студию? Я про сборку через терминал

Comment: да. студия добавляет всяких приятностей, но всю работу делает gradle. в корне проекта должен быть build.gradle и в нем описано как собирать.

Comment: Ну пишите код в блокноте, а собирайте вручную.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AIDE не трогал и не собираюсь, но AndroidStudio вы зря ругаете.

Я могу сравнивать лишь с Eclipse, но качественное улучшение удобности создания приложений - налицо. "Лишние кнопочки" - либо полезны, либо можно их просто игнорировать. Как они могут мешать - непонятно.

Автодополнение и предложения исправить - чудесная вещь. Если вы имеете достаточный опыт написания кода то предлагаемые студией подсказки вещь безмерно удобная и полезная. После неудобства Eclipse эта фича студии вызывает восторг.

Насколько я понял из ваших предыдущих вопросов в AIDE либы подключаются также как в Eclipse - путём скачивания и копирования jar файлов. После такого система сборки gradle выглядит переусложнённой и непонятной, да. Но, когда в ней удаётся разобраться сразу видны все её преимущества. В самом простом случае добавление либы происходит всего лишь добавление 1 строки в один файл. А если копнуть глубже то там множество возможностей, включая, но не заканчивая, возможностью настроить несколько вариантов сборки (релиз/дебаг, платная/бесплатная версия etc до бесконечности), в эти варианты добавить различные переменные, значение коих зависит от типа сборки, настроить версионоирование билдов для ContinuosIntergation (это для промышленного изготовления софта, если есть QA отдел). К тому же, настколько я понимаю, gradle сборка - современный стандарт и многие крутые либы просто не смогут без неё работать. Сюда можно включить либы с кодогенерацией типа Dagger2, Realm, ButterKnife, Mosby - после их освоения понимаешь что раньше написание кода было болью.

А настроить цвета ключевых и прочих слов в коде можно в настройках студии. Там вообще можно много чего настроить. Ваше возмущение выглядит как будто вы взяли в руки компьютер после многолетнего пользования инженерным калькулятором.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Весьма странная претензия надо сказать, но вы можете обратиться к настройкам и поотключать там все инспекции, так же как и настроить любые цвета как на свой вкус, так и используя какую-то [готовую тему](http://color-themes.com/?view=index).

Если студия предлагает все исправить, с большой долей вероятности это нужно исправить, а не в панике отключать рекомендации по рефакторингу. Немного самонадеяно думать, что вы знаете лучше системы Lint.

Очевидно основная проблема у вас в том, что вы не умеете пользоваться возможностями Android Studio, этот пробел нужно [срочно восполнить](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html) и тогда она превратится из непонятного монстра в доброго помощника.

PS: первый раз вижу, чтобы кто то хотел назад в Блокнот :) . Что бы вы о Microsoft Visual Studio интересно тогда сказали.